# Windows Identity Foundation(WIF) - Does it work with legacy ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

I've seen a bunch of examples getting ASP.NET to work with WIF, but what about some of the old legacy ASP applications? We've got some sitting around our Intranet and I'm curious if the old code will work with WIF's authentication/authorization schemes. We won't be re-writing them for a good while.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misread your question as ASP.NET, not classic ASP.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write an entire intermediate applciation. You can wrap all access to WIF on a .NET class that is exposed as a COM object. (This is using standard .NET interop capabilities)

It shouldn't be a big effort. Of course this assumes you have .NET 3.5 installed in the same boxes you have the ASP application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx):

> Windows Identity Foundation enables
>   .NET developers to...

You might be able to use WIF with ASP, but only if you go through a .NET intermediate app, which is probably way more trouble than it's worth.